# Undefined method 'id' for Class, but the console loads fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

I can access the shopping_list_products loaded in this API call from the console with no error.

I get a 500 on the API, however:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for #<Class:0x007f6cca7e1dd0>):
2015-01-26T23:51:07.608697+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: collection :@shopping_list_products
2015-01-26T23:51:07.608699+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: extends 'api/v1/shopping_list_products/_show'
```

index.json.rabl:

```
collection :@shopping_list_products
extends 'api/v1/shopping_list_products/_show'
```

show.json.rabl:

```
object :@shopping_list_product
extends 'api/v1/shopping_list_products/_show'
```

_show.json.rabl:

```
object :shopping_list_product
attribute(:id, :if => lambda { |m| m.id })
attributes :shopping_list_retailer_id, :product_id, ...

... more attributes

child :product, partial: 'api/v1/products/_show'
child :product_category, partial: 'api/v1/product_categories/_show'

node(:url) do |shopping_list_product|
  api_v1_schedule_requisition_plan_shopping_list_shopping_list_retailer_shopping_list_product_path(@schedule, @shopping_list_retailer, shopping_list_product, format: :json)
end
```

EDIT: I removed the id attribute and then ran into the next error, "undefined method shopping_list_retailer_id for Class:". Why is this happening?

EDIT: Found out it's my code called from the controller.. if I return

`@shopping_list_retailer.shopping_list_products`

it works fine.

But I do this instead:

```
api :GET, '/schedule/:schedule_id/requisition_plan/shopping_list/shopping_list_retailers/:shopping_list_retailer_id/shopping_list_products', 'List all shopping list products for Shopping List for Requisition Plans for Schedule in the database'
param :query, String, desc: "Scoped_search style query string"
def index
  @shopping_list_products = ShoppingListProductsIndexQuery.new(@shopping_list_retailer, params[:query]).shopping_list_products
end

class ShoppingListProductsIndexQuery
  attr_reader :shopping_list_retailer, :query
  def initialize(shopping_list_retailer, query)
    @shopping_list_retailer = shopping_list_retailer
    @query = query
  end

  def shopping_list_products
    @shopping_list_retailer.shopping_list_products.ordered_by_product_category_type_and_product_category_name_and_product_name.search_for(query)
  end
end
```

Still confused why undefined method id for Class is hit in the rabl view.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message `(undefined method 'id' for #<Class:0x007f6cca7e1dd0>)` is saying the undefined method is on an instance of `Class` instead of an instance of `ShoppingListProduct` (or whatever your actual class name is).

This means the wrong thing is being rendered.

Probably because you are using:

```
object :@shopping_list_products
# and
object :@shopping_list_product
```

Instead of:

```
object @shopping_list_products
# and
object @shopping_list_product
```

Remove the `:`s.

Also, in your `_show.json.rabl` file, you really don't need

```
object :shopping_list_product
```

as this is ignored when the RABL template is being used as a partial (https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Reusing-templates)